# Shopify | Making the default value for a product drop-down box say 'Pick an option' / 'Pick a Size'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify

I'm using the Grid Theme and trying to work through a customization that defaults to "Pick A Size" instead of "Small" in product.liquid. (Client is seeing too many incorrect "Small" orders from people ordering the default size).

Working through this:

https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/how-to-add-a-pick-an-option-to-drop-downs

However, searching for `new Shopify.OptionSelectors` per the doc above has been fruitless -- can't find it anywhere in my theme files.

My hunch is that it is actually buried somewhere in `option_selection.js` which is a Shopify (server-side) asset and can't be directly edited.

Here's what I've got in `product.liquid` (for what it's worth):

```
<div class="product-options">
    <select class="product-variants" name="id" id="product-variants-{{ product.id }}">
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
        <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
</div>
```

and, not sure if this is connected, I also have:

```
<script>
  // required for splitting variants
  // see ProductView
  window.products["{{ product.id }}"] = {{ product | json }};
  FirstVariant["{{ product.id }}"] = {{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id | json }};
</script>
```

EDIT: Commenting out the `<option>` lines in the above code, and the size dropdown fires as is regardless of being commented out or not. This leads me to believe the issue is with `{{ product.id }}`

Comment: little out of the topic, but can we add items to the shopify store programatically @sOrf

Comment: @gates not sure about this, basically each product has variants, including size. I was hoping to add a new default using JQuery, still working on it however..

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to remove the default and force the user to pick a value? I would do something like this then:

```
<div class="product-options">
<select class="product-variants" name="id" id="product-variants-{{ product.id }}">
    <option selected="selected" disabled>Pick A Size</option>
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
    <option value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

I also removed the if statement that includes the selected attribute if the product has the selected attribute or if it's the first available variant. These will not be needed if you want the default to always be "Pick An Option".

The disabled attribute I added to the first option is for the purpose of not allowing the user to select it again once they've opened up the select menu.

Comment: Had an Ahh haaa moment there when you posted, however, havn't got it to work yet. But this led me to comment out each `option` line, and the size dropdown shows up regardless of being commented out or not.. still working on this solution, thanks

Comment: sounds like the template may be coming from somewhere else

Comment: certainly coming from `id="product-variants-{{ product.id }}"`... still haven't been able to drop in a default selector :/

Answer (score 0):

## Update:

[Shopify official doc for this feature](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/variants/how-to-add-a-pick-an-option-to-drop-downs)